# Duplicate image and set hover CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, arrows

I want to make the following animation:

[image]

One div with 2 same arrows and on hover first arrow should move on left/right. I tried to do it, but it unsuccessfully. I'm setting background with 2 images, but how I can set animation for 1 of the images like the gif?

```
.arrow-right2 {
    content: "";
    background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png) 0 -185px no-repeat, transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png) 0 -185px no-repeat;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5%;
    left: 0;
    width: 35px;
}
```

Comment: can you share the real image of the arrow?

Comment: Its a sprite -> https://imgur.com/a/Ql49ftI

Comment: I edited my answer to include the color change

Answer (score 5):

Try to use 2 different divs with the same arrows, with position absolute and use this to overlap the two arrows. If you can, use a single image, not a sprite. Then apply the effect on hover on one of the images.

```css
body {
  background: red;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow1 {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png') no-repeat -17px -199px;
 width: 12px;
 height: 24px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.arrow2 {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png') no-repeat -17px -199px;
 width: 12px;
 height: 24px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  left: 0;
}
.arrow2:hover {
  left: -10px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow1">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats okay, but how to change the arrow color to red on hover, like the gif?

Comment: You must add a red arrow into the sprite, or start using SVG images that allow you to change the image color in CSS. Or using two single png images in the two different colors.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust `background-position` like below. You start with a different position for each one then you make them the same:

```css
.arrow {
  background: 
   url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png) -10px -185px,      
   url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png) 10px -185px,
   red;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background-position:10px -185px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Or the opposite

```css
.arrow {
  background: 
   url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png),      
   url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png),
   red;
  background-position:10px -185px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background-position:
    -10px -185px,
    10px -185px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

And if you want to adjust coloration you can consider `mix-blend-mode`

```css
.arrow {
  background: 
   url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png),      
   url(https://i.imgur.com/u7cYXIo.png),
   #000;
  background-position:10px -185px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
  position:relative;
}
.arrow:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: red;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background-position:
    -10px -185px,
    10px -185px;
}
.arrow:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```